# How to ask a user how many inputs they want

Tags: python, array

I want to know if it possible to use arrays for a more viable alternative of getting a non-predetermined number of inputs as an array and with an indefinite number of inputs. (python)

original code -->

```
if inputs == 1:
    print("more than 1")
elif inputs == 2:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 3:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 4:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a4 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 5:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a4 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a5 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 6:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a4 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a5 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a6 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 7:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a4 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a5 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a6 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a7 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 8:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a4 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a5 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a6 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a7 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a8 = int(input("type integer\n"))
elif inputs == 9:
    a1 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a2 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a3 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a4 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a5 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a6 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a7 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a8 = int(input("type integer\n"))
    a9 = int(input("type integer\n"))
else:
    print("less then 10")
```

Comment: Don't use variables this way.  Use an Array or collection instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are many many ways to do this. As I can tell you're beginner I will give you some simple viable possibilities.

There are a few ways to approach this. You can first simply ask the user how can't entries they would like to enter and use a loop construct to grab input until you reach the number they gave.

OR

A better way might be to have a trigger word that the user enters to signify they are done giving data. For example they type all entries and at the end they maybe type "--" and you end the loop when you receive that input.

Remember if you are doing something over and over consider using a loop! Keep learning programming well takes time and effort.